# Data shown with ui:repeat but not with p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

The rendering of a search mask works with `ui:repeat` but not with `p:dataTable`. Can someone explain this?

Working:

```
<p:panelGrid>
    <ui:repeat value="#{curSearch.getSearchMaskDescription().getRows()}" var="curRow" varStatus="rowStatus">
        <p:row >
            <ui:repeat value="#{curRow.getElements()}" var="curMaskElement" varStatus="colStatus">
                <p:column colspan="#{curMaskElement.columnSpan}">

                    <mycomp:searchFieldCC isShortSearchMask="false" curMaskElement="#{curMaskElement}" curRowIndex="#{rowIndexVar}"
                        curColumnIndex="#{columnIndexVar}" />

                </p:column>
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:row>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Not working:

```
<p:dataTable id="searchMaskTableId" value="#{curSearch.getSearchMaskDescription().getRows()}" var="curRow" rowIndexVar="rowIndexVar"
    styleClass="searchMaskFieldsGrid">
    <p:columns value="#{curRow.getElements()}" var="curMaskElement" columnIndexVar="columnIndexVar" colspan="#{curMaskElement.columnSpan}">

        <mycomp:searchFieldCC isShortSearchMask="false" curMaskElement="#{curMaskElement}" curRowIndex="#{rowIndexVar}" curColumnIndex="#{columnIndexVar}" />

    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

The difference is only the iteration I think. `ui:repeat` is built in another phase, but I had expected that the `ui:repeat` does not work instead.
The rendered html with `p:dataTable`:

```
<div id="searchInstancesFormId:searchMaskTableId" class="ui-datatable ui-widget searchMaskFieldsGrid">
    <div class="ui-datatable-tablewrapper">
        <table role="grid">
            <thead id="searchInstancesFormId:searchMaskTableId_head">
                <tr role="row"></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="searchInstancesFormId:searchMaskTableId_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content">
                <tr data-ri="0" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"></tr>
                <tr data-ri="1" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"></tr>
                <tr data-ri="2" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"></tr>
                <tr data-ri="3" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"></tr>
                <tr data-ri="4" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are not columns rendered. Why? 
The form is updated via ajax.
The data model is correct.

Comment: Wrong usage (as do many) of the columns tags. You cannot create columns for individual rows (what if they have a different number of columns). See the PF showcase on how to use it, or one of the many duplicate questions in stackoverflow

Comment: Ok. Would it work if I fill dummy column to achieve that all rows have the same column count? A log warning would be nice in this case.

Comment: Just read the duplicate, it is all in there...